# Is there a faster method can checkif words in a sentences list in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

I have a dictionary words list and a sentences list, now I need to check **each** word(all are different) if in **each**  sentence(all are different) so I my code like that,

```
word_list = ["人", "天", "地"] #over 100 ords in actual dict
input_file = ["你是不是经常也告诉自己", "不管发生什么事情", "都要微笑着面对生活"] #over 1000 sentences 

output = []
for line in input_file:
    for word in word_list:
        if word in line:
            output.append(word)
```

However, I was wondering if it will cost much more time if I use two-loops, is there some better method can finish this job, what about using dict?

Comment: make word_list a set and then use `in` worrd_list.Seaching will be `O(1)` in `sets`

Comment: @vks I think you meant `line` into a set. And still, strictly speaking the total algorithmic complexity can not be lowered. As you said @4daJKong, you need to check for **every** word and **every** line in the file. So with `m` words and `n` lines you can not theoretically get lower than `O(n * m)`.

Comment: `for line in map(set, input_file)`, if each element in your `word_list` is a Chinese character.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg so whichever will be the bigger list, we should make it a set...and if you dont make a set...it would O(n3)...with set...O(n2)...lot faster

Comment: @vks okay, so there maybe no improvement in algo, what about in python coding, is there some way in coding method?

Comment: @vks Sorry, this is just wrong. The only sensible data to turn into a set would be each line in the file since OP wants to check if a word is in a line. Why would you turn the words list into a set? Iteration will take just as long as with a list.

Comment: @4daJKong By the way: Do you actually want to append the word every time? Please define desired output given a specific input. I am asking because with your current implementation, the `output` may contain a bunch of duplicates at the end and its length will have nothing in common with the length of the input file.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg I need to check each word if in one sentence, then get the occurance of each word in ouput, the second task is if each word, all are not in this sentence, then skip this sentence.

Comment: @4daJKong when you make set and search in it there is a massive improvement.O(1) vs O(n).

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg iteration will be O(n) in any case...long or short...my point is when searching, we need to make a set....so searching smaller list in larger list will make more sense than seaching learger in smaller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand my comment:

Given a list of words of length `m` and a file with `n` lines with an average line length of `l`, the following applies.

To turn *one* line into a set of words, you will have to iterate once over it: *O(`l`)*.

To turn **every** line into a set of words will therefore be in *O(`n * l`)*.

To check if *one* word is in that set of words, you need to do a set-lookup: *O(`1`)*.

To check **every** word will therefore be in *O(`m`)*.

To do that for **every** line will therefore be in *O(`n * m`)*.

Comment: And so the final complexity will be O(`n (l + m)`). This is better than the OP's O(`n l m`).